# Converting H:M:S character variable to numeric/continuous scale (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, lubridate

I am interested in visualizing twitter sentiment over a given topic per hour, and my variables are stored as follows:

```
sapply(valence_hour,class)
      Time          day mean_valence            n 
 "character"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "integer"
```

Here is a data example:

```
Time          day   mean_valence            n 
23:59:00     19     0.0909090909            3
23:58:00     19     0.0589743590            3
23:57:00     19     0.49743590             3
```

I then ran the following code for a graph:

```
ggplot(valence_hour, aes(x = Time, y = mean_valence)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,30,1)) +
  geom_smooth()
```

However, I keep receiving this error: "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

To resolve this issue which I believe is caused by the "Time" variable stored as character, I tried to implement a solution similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65013970/convert-hms-character-into-number).
I ran the following, which runs without errors but it's not solving the issue with my "Time" variable as I still receive the error "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

```
valence_hour <-
  time_to_seconds <- function(time) {
  
  parts <- time %>% 
    strsplit(":|\\.") %>% 
    .[[1]] %>% 
    as.numeric
  
  seconds <- parts[1] * 60 * 60 + parts[2] * 60 + parts[3]
  
  seconds
}

time_to_seconds("00:01:53.910")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way.
Concatenate the current system date and `Time`, coerce to `"POSIXct"` and use this new, temp variable for the x-axis. Set the axis labels in a datetime layer.

The warnings are due to the small data set, `loess` complains about not having enough data points. Don't worry about it, it will work with bigger data.

```r
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE)
library(ggplot2, quietly = TRUE)

x <- '
Time          day   mean_valence            n 
23:59:00     19     0.0909090909            3
23:58:00     19     0.0589743590            3
23:57:00     19     0.49743590             3'
valence_hour <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

valence_hour %>%
  mutate(Time = paste(Sys.Date(), Time),
         Time = as.POSIXct(Time)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, mean_valence)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_datetime(
    date_breaks = "1 mins",
    date_labels = "%H:%M:%S"
  ) +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "loess")
#> Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric =
#> parametric, : span too small. fewer data values than degrees of freedom.
#> Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric =
#> parametric, : pseudoinverse used at 1.654e+09
#> Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric =
#> parametric, : neighborhood radius 60.6
#> Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric =
#> parametric, : reciprocal condition number 0
#> Warning in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric =
#> parametric, : There are other near singularities as well. 3672.4
#> Warning in predLoess(object$y, object$x, newx = if
#> (is.null(newdata)) object$x else if (is.data.frame(newdata))
#> as.matrix(model.frame(delete.response(terms(object)), : span too small. fewer
#> data values than degrees of freedom.
#> Warning in predLoess(object$y, object$x, newx = if
#> (is.null(newdata)) object$x else if (is.data.frame(newdata))
#> as.matrix(model.frame(delete.response(terms(object)), : pseudoinverse used at
#> 1.654e+09
#> Warning in predLoess(object$y, object$x, newx = if
#> (is.null(newdata)) object$x else if (is.data.frame(newdata))
#> as.matrix(model.frame(delete.response(terms(object)), : neighborhood radius 60.6
#> Warning in predLoess(object$y, object$x, newx = if
#> (is.null(newdata)) object$x else if (is.data.frame(newdata))
#> as.matrix(model.frame(delete.response(terms(object)), : reciprocal condition
#> number 0
#> Warning in predLoess(object$y, object$x, newx = if
#> (is.null(newdata)) object$x else if (is.data.frame(newdata))
#> as.matrix(model.frame(delete.response(terms(object)), : There are other near
#> singularities as well. 3672.4
#> Warning in max(ids, na.rm = TRUE): no non-missing arguments to max; returning
#> -Inf
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Convinced by the solution of @Rui Barradas, here is an alternative approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

valence_hour %>% 
  mutate(Time = hms(Time)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = mean_valence)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_time()+
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]